# Is it possible to automate ssh login WITH passwd (not passphraseless ssh)

Tags: bash, ssh, passwords

Regardless of security issues, I want to automate ssh login by putting password into a script file (in form of plaintext). For example, I tried following, but without success...

> echo "mypassword" | ssh -X root@remote_node_address

it still prompt with password inputs...

Edit: I am aware of setting up passphraseless ssh (and actually have done this). What my question really is is how to automate process of setting up passphraseless ssh...

Comment: You might rather try [generating passphraseless key](http://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password)..

Comment: Check out man page here http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh+1 which mentions that "The user creates his/her key pair by running ssh-keygen(1)."  and following is this statement "After this, the user can log in with-out giving the password."

Comment: @MichalKlouda I want to even automate the process of setting up passphraseless ssh.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Automate with Expect

You can use [Expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) to drive password authentication with SSH. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no host.example.com
expect -exact "Password: "
send -- "secret\r"
expect {\$\s*} { interact }
```

This script is a very basic example, and not especially robust in the face of failure or when running under a non-standard remote *TERM* like GNU screen, but it works for the common case. You can also use */usr/bin/autoexpect* from the **expect-dev** package to generate your own custom scripts based on a manual session.

Comment: See [Can Expect understand screen-oriented (Curses) programs?](http://expect.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#q22) for some pointers on how to get Expect to work with GNU screen.

Comment: @Richard It's a regular expression that looks for a standard shell prompt, then issues the *interact* command when it's seen. Most expect commands are in pattern/action pairs, although more complex configurations are possible.

Answer (score 2):

you will need to use public key authentication, see

http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html

in order to add new keys for existing hosts, you will need to automate updating of public keys in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on remote machine

it is easy to do with

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 1024 -f ~/.ssh/new-key -P ""
cat ~/.ssh/new-key.pub | ssh root@target-host 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

then you can use new key to access host with

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/new-key root@remote-host
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into [empty](http://empty.sourceforge.net/) recently. I am surprised that it seems not to be well known since it is rarely talked about when problems like "how to automate ssh" arise.

I use it on openwrt, it has a package about 7KB in size without dependency, while tcl package is around 440KB. And you can use it in shell directly.

"empty is an utility that provides an interface to execute and/or interact with processes under pseudo-terminal sessions (PTYs). This tool is definitely useful in programming of shell scripts designed to communicate with interactive programs like telnet, ssh, ftp, etc. In some cases empty can be the simplest replacement for TCL/expect or other similar programming tools "

For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

empty -f -i in -o out telnet foo.bar.com
empty -w -i out -o in "ogin:" "luser\n"
empty -w -i out -o in "assword:" "TopSecret\n"
empty -s -o in "who am i\n"
empty -s -o in "exit\n"
```